# glCheckFramebufferStatus returns 36054 GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT

Tags: android, opengl-es, framebuffer, fbo, render-to-texture

This is just to share something that took me a long time to figure out. If you don't need your Depthbuffer or don't have a Depth Buffer Attachment Point setup in EGL this might help.

For some reason I couldn't get rendering to texture to work setting the render buffer object RBO to depth buffer: like so

```
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
            GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
            juliaTex[0], 0);
    rain.checkGlError("glFramebufferTexture2D");
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
            GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
            juliaRBO[0]);
    rain.checkGlError("glFramebufferRenderbuffer");

    int status = GLES20.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
```

Causes error `status == GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`

If I change render buffer storage to `GLES20.GL_RGBA4`, as opposed to `GLES20.DEPTH_COMPONENT16` and change `GLES20.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` to `GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` then the error goes away,

Change this

```
    // create render buffer and bind 16-bit depth buffer
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, juliaRBO[0]);
    rain.checkGlError("glBindRenderBuffer");
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.DEPTH_COMPONENT16, 
            rain.width, rain.height);
```

to this

```
    // create render buffer and bind 16-bit depth buffer
    GLES20.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, juliaRBO[0]);
    rain.checkGlError("glBindRenderBuffer");
    GLES20.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES20.GL_RGBA4, 
            rain.width, rain.height);
```

And the original code to this:

```
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
            GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
            juliaTex[0], 0);
    rain.checkGlError("glFramebufferTexture2D");
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
            GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
            juliaRBO[0]);
    rain.checkGlError("glFramebufferRenderbuffer");
```

then `status == GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE`

But the texture is empty.

here is the call to create storage texture

```
    // bind texture
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, juliaTex[0]);

    // clamp texture to edges
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    rain.checkGlError("glTexParameter JuliaTex");

    // create it
    /*
    int[] buf = new int[rain.width * rain.height];
    juliaTexBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(buf.length
            * rain.FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer();
     */
    // generate the textures
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 
            rain.width, rain.height, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, 
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_4_4_4_4, null);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

To get this to work in addition to attaching the render buffer to the color attachment point I swapped the order of the Framebuffer attachments:

```
    GLES20.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
            GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_RENDERBUFFER, 
            juliaRBO[0]);
    rain.checkGlError("glFramebufferRenderbuffer");
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 
            GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
            juliaTex[0], 0);
    rain.checkGlError("glFramebufferTexture2D");
```

So that Texture2D is attached to the Framebuffer color layer after Renderbuffer. I assume the last connection point is the point OpenGL ES uses.

Comment: **-1**: You did more than simply attach the texture last in this code. You actually attached your renderbuffer to attachment point **0** and then replaced that attachment with your texture image. This is very different from what you tried originally. Please update your question to show how you allocate the storage for your texture and your renderbuffer, as that is almost certainly where your error is ***actually*** coming from. With this current setup, you have no depth buffer.

Comment: I don't think my EGL setup has a Depth buffer attachment point. Which is what was causing the error. You probably know a lot more about this stuff than I, and this solution might seem silly, but it is just a workaround which will probably help more hackers than messing around with the Depth Component Attachment Point. to each his own

Comment: All FBOs have a depth buffer attachment point, but the format and dimensions of the RBO / texture image you are allowed to attach there can be very restrictive. The primary problem I can see right now is that your texture `juliaTex [0]` probably does not have the same dimensions as your RBO, that is why I was asking to see how you allocated storage for that texture. There is no reason to even create / attach the RBO doing what you're doing right now, because you immediately bind something else over the RBO.

Comment: The framebuffer status returns incomplete if I try to bypass binding a render buffer. adding texture storage call